# pass JSON object from javascript function to a java controller class using spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I need to send a JSON object from javascript function which is called on submit from a form in jsp page to a java spring mvc controller class and call a service method "/resetpassword" in the controller class.
Thankz in advance.

Comment: what is wrong with the question why am I getting negative votes.

Comment: You are being downvoted probably because you've started a question with : "I need..." but without showing what you've tried so far (no visible effort in solving the problem by yourself). StackOverflow is not a pool of programmers waiting to write whole solutions for you but rather a people eager to help you when you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a json in java script and pass the json using ajax call

```
var JSONObject= {"uname":uname, "password":password };
var jsonData = JSON.parse( JSONObject );    

var request = $.ajax({
url: "/yoururlhere",
type: "POST",
data: jsonData,
dataType: "json"
});
```

then in your controller get the json like

```
String contactJsonData = request.getParameter("data");
```

and change the string to map

```
 HashMap contactJson =  objectMapper.readValue( contactJsonData , HashMap.class);
```

now you can use your data from the map 
Hope it will help you